# How to measure elapsed time on a processor executing code in a Fortran OpenMP thread

Tags: time, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I used cpu_time, but apparently that gives the total time for all threads. I used omp_get_wtime, but get an output in the negatives which is not correct, and also mpi_wtime for which I am now getting a core dump (and for which earlier I was getting just 0.000000000). The relevant code is as follows:

```
      real*8 tbeg, tend
      ....
      !$omp sections private (ie, tbeg, tend)
          !$omp section
              tbeg = omp_get_wtime()
              do ie=1, E
                  call rmul(u, A, B, dudr, duds, dudt, ie)
              enddo
              tend = omp_get_wtime()
              !Step 4: Print results
              print *, tend-tbeg
          !$omp end section
          !$omp section
          ....
          !$omp end section
      !$omp  end sections
```

My compile option is:

```
gfortran -Ofast -c mult.f -o mult.o -mcmodel=large -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -fopenmp
gfortran -o baseline ../lib/performance_test.o mult.o ../lib/rose.o -lcuda -lcudart -L/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64 -lcublas -lgomp -lmpi_f77
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you shouldn't be able to privatise a variable in a `section` block directive, only at the `sections` enclosing directive's level (NB the section**s** vs. section)... Are you actually compiling this code?

Comment: @Gilles you are correct. The clauses (such as `private`) should appear in the `sections` construct level. However, when I have made this mistake in my own code, the compiler has allowed what OP has done, essentially ignoring it. This will probably fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the correct usage of sections versus section. Though the compiler did not complain, I find cpu_time to be working fine now, as well as system_clock.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It is explicitly written that  `omg_get_wtime` returns wall clock time in seconds since some *arbitrary* time in the past (OpenMP 4.0 §3.4.1). Additionally, this arbitrary starting time is not necessarily consistent between threads.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark and Stefan... omp_get_wtime still does not work for me. The two calls (at the beginning and end), as well as their subtraction gives arbitrary values. These are respectively: 1.0916406707093504E+017  -1.8492953257686187E+022   1.8493062421753258E+022. Obviously there is something wrong in the usage, but I can't immediately figure out what that is. system_clock works fine for me though, and I am using it for now.

Comment: It's now clear that this question is off-topic, it does not *include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*.  This is clear from the answer and OP's comment on the answer.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Thanks for keeping a tab on the problem and also for suggesting to use omp_get_wtime. The problem begun as inability to measure time with any function and evolved along the way.

Comment: I always use the intrinsic SYSTEM_CLOCK https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM_005fCLOCK.html whatever theading or other parallel library I use/ It is basic Fortran and you don't have to change it when enabling different libraries.

Comment: @VladimirF - Thanks for the feedback. system_clock worked fine for me too, even as I was having problems with omp_get_wtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to reproduce your issue (with some difficulties, but I've got it). And I'm pretty sure that the bottom line is that you forgot two things in your code:

1. To include either the OpenMP header `include 'omp_lib.h'` or better the OpenMP module `use omp_lib`
2. To forbid implicit variables declaration `implicit none`

Although the latter isn't strictly speaking an error, it's definitely a good habit to take and which would have spare you the actual issue coming from the former, since you would have had the following message from the compiler:

```
tbeg = omp_get_wtime()
      1 Error: Function 'omp_get_wtime' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

So what happened is that you implicitly declared `omp_get_wtime` as a function returning a single precision floating point variable whereas it actually returns a double precision one. So the return value was truncated and you were having garbage.

Just add the right header and use `omp_get_wtime()` as you have in you code snippet, and everything should be all-right.

Comment: Thanks a ton for taking the pains to recreate the issue. These fixes indeed solved the problem...